# Words or expressions describing really bad modern music

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

I need some words, or expressions describing tuneless, jarring, thumping, off-key music. The best word I know is `cacophony`. Are there better words, are there words describing the worst of specific genres?

The word describes some really bad music blaring at a bar in a scene of my novel. The music can be of any genre, but the bar is a student bar in the typical American small university town.

Comment: @Cascabel I edited out my opinion. Is it better?

Comment: @Cascabel I don't think you're right at all. What if there is a specific word for bad medieval music and a different specific word for bad modern country music? I think I could ask another more focused question, but the typical answer you get when you focus the question too much is nothing. In any case, feel free to edit, or close. I needed an answer to describe some really bad music blaring at a bar in a scene in my novel.

Comment: @Cascabel I made an edit. Hope it helps.